# How to convert non-standard sample range to standard

Tags: matlab, analog-to-digital, pcm

I'm working on a project to record sound from a Raspberry Pi. I have ADC values ranging from 0 to 4095. I can convert it to an audio file and hear my voice. 12-bit ADC resolution with a sample rate of 48kHz This is my algorithm for getting sample ranges in MATLAB:
`(ADC Value / 2047.5) - 1`

It works great but the problem is that is not standard

[image]
I need a standard sample range like a Windows audio recorder 32768 and -32768.

Comment: `y = (x-2048)*16`

Comment: I tried it, it only increases the amplitude

Comment: I want to make normalize like Audacity

Comment: Then please edit your question describe exactly what you want to do, what's currently not working and what your constraints are.

Comment: In your plot you show the sampling rate as 44000 but you said you sampled at 48KHz. 44.1 KHz is common for audio, are you trying to resample to or from 48 KHz or was that a typo? The plot also shows the waveform is always negative; are you trying to remove that DC offset and make it a signed number?

Comment: The typographical error is 48,000 kHz for another image But The problem is the same

Comment: @Dan Boschen
I want to remove DC offset like Audacity
And I can fix this with Audacity

Comment: @Dan Boschen
But I don't know what the formula is?

Comment: @Hilmar
I explained here

Comment: @Hilmar thank you for your attention

Comment: To remove DC just subtract the mean

Comment: For example, with what number?